# Arraylist program

Tags: java

I did a program but the output shows `0`. Could you see what I did wrong?
My assessment instructions ask this.

```
package snippet;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CO2FromElectricity {
    // declaration of private instance variables

    /**
     * Default constructor to create an object from the CO2FromElectricity class.
     */
    CO2FromElectricity() {
    }

    /**
     * A mutator method which calculates the average annual electricity bill.
     * 
     * @param monthlyBill
     *            an ArrayList containing the monthly bills for home electricity use.
     * @return the average monthly electricity bill.
     */
    public double calcAverageBill(ArrayList<Double> monthlyBill) {
        monthlyBill.add(279.41);
        monthlyBill.add(238.03);
        monthlyBill.add(248.64);
        monthlyBill.add(258.73);
        monthlyBill.add(395.48);
        monthlyBill.add(419.91);
        monthlyBill.add(431.15);
        monthlyBill.add(407.56);
        monthlyBill.add(417.14);
        monthlyBill.add(308.35);
        monthlyBill.add(337.91);
        monthlyBill.add(320.77);
        double sum = 0.0;
        double monthlyTotal = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < monthlyBill.size(); i++) {
            sum += monthlyBill.get(i);
        }

        return monthlyTotal / monthlyBill.size();
    }

    /**
     * A mutator method which calculates the average annual price of electricity.
     * 
     * @param monthlyPrice
     *            an ArrayList containing the monthly price of electricity per kilowatthour.
     * @return the average monthly price of electricity.
     */
    public double calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice) {
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1117);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1107);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1110);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1113);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1135);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1138);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1217);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1215);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1216);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1228);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1209);
        monthlyPrice.add(0.1192);
        double sum = 0.0;
        double monthlyTotal = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < monthlyPrice.size(); i++) {
            sum += monthlyPrice.get(i);
        }
        return monthlyTotal / monthlyPrice.size();
    }

    /**
     * A mutator method which calculates the annual home CO2 emission from electricity.
     * 
     * @param avgBill
     *            the average monthly home electricity bill.
     * @param avgPrice
     *            the average monthly price of home electricity.
     * @return the annual home CO2 emission from home electricity use.
     */
    public double calcElectricityCO2(double avgBill, double avgPrice) {
        return (avgBill / avgPrice) * 1.37 * 12;
    }
}
```

The output should be like the following. Please see what I did wrong.

> ```
> Average Monthly Electricity Bill: 191.23  
> Average Monthly Electricity Price: 0.11  
> Annual CO2 Emissions from Electricity Usage: 28667.1 pounds
> ```

Comment: Where is your output method? You do a bunch of calculations, but never do anything to display them. How are these methods being called? It looks like you've provided a fragment.

Comment: Is this your complete code you have written?

Comment: You did not provided the code, which invokes this methods and do output.

Comment: I did return (avgBill/avgPrice) * 1.37 * 12; is that right? Or displaying the output is the part I did wrong?

Comment: Yes it is the whole program i did.

Comment: Where is your main method?Where you are calling the calcAveragePrice() and calcAverageBill() methods?

Comment: @Palpatim This is a very common mistake made by beginners. I TA'd an introductory CS class and I lost count of how many times I had to explain that just because you've defined a function, it's not going to do anything unless you call it.

Comment: @user1928899 to display results you can use `System.out.println("Somthing to print");`.

Comment: I guess your friend purposefully removed some part from the code before giving it to you;-)

Comment: Take a look at where you are calculating the totals. You have a variable that you are storing the summation, but use a variable set to 0 to perform the calculation....

Comment: @user1928899 follow this link. [Java tutorial for beginners - Introduction](http://www.freejavaguide.com/corejava.htm). another link [Methods](http://www.freejavaguide.com/corejava4.htm)

Comment: @NullUserException *facepalm* :)

Comment: @user1928899 This is video link [Java video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cfd9DOnuF9w)

Answer (score 1):

Monthly Total is always 0.0. So your function is returning 0.0/sum

Comment: This is *a* problem, but I'm not sure this is what the OP is referring to when they say the output is 0. Since no output method is called, I'm guessing 0 is just the return code for the program.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I assumed there would be a print statement somewhere, and got tunnel vision on the math.

Answer (score 0):

the output is 0 because you write:

```
double monthlyTotal = 0.0;
```

i think you want to

```
 return  sum/monthlyPrice.size();
```